# IF Else statements in SQL Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write if else in SQL Server Update Query.

[image]

Comment: so what was the issue?

Comment: i want to write the update with  if else. actually not a issue. :)

Comment: Do you have to use `IF ELSE`? For your requirement, you could search for `CASE statement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TempTable]
SET [Level1] = CASE WHEN A = -1 THEN 0 ELSE A END
   ,[Level2] = CASE WHEN A = -1 THEN 0 ELSE A END;
```

You need to use `CASE` in such scenarios. Try the above query..

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using **IF**, you can try the following:

**IF**

```
IF A = -1 BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[TempTable]
    SET [Level1] = 0
       ,[Level2] = 0
END
ELSE BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[TempTable]
    SET [Level1] = A
       ,[Level2] = A
END
```

**IIF**

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TempTable]
SET [Level1] = IIF(A = -1, 0, A)
   ,[Level2] = IIF(A = -1, 0, A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statement, and If "A" is one of the column in your dbo.TempTable

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(A INT,Level1 INT,Level2 INT)

INSERT @Table
SELECT -1, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,NULL,NULL

UPDATE t SET 
    Level1 = CASE WHEN A = -1 THEN 0 ELSE A END,
    Level2 = CASE WHEN A = -1 THEN 0 ELSE A END
FROM @Table t

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

-- Result

```
A   Level1  Level2
-1  0   0
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

With case or IIF ;)

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TempTable]
SET [Level1] = IIF(A = -1 , 0 , A),  [Level2] = IIF(A = -1 , 0 , A)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work**:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TempTable]
SET [Level1] = IIF(A = -1, 0, A), [Level2] = IIF(A = -1, 0, A);
```